# Disableing button once its clicked even after going back or restarting application

Tags: android, api, listview, signature, sign

I am making and application in which after login I get multiple list of "orders" like order 1, order 2, order 3 etc depending on the data coming from the API. in single order having details like order no, latitude longitude and many more. I want that on the particular order click  ex. like i have clicked on order no 1 (Every order no is unique) page will redirect next page having a button named "Signature" after clicking on the it will redirect to next page having three option's. Options are these confirmed(Button),picked(Button),
delivered(Button). on these button events i am calling a page on which i am taking a signature and sending that signature on server.(Till now i have done all coding and working fine). The thing i want is once the signature is done the button should be disabled for the particular order no ex. like i clicked on the confirmed button of order no 1 and done the signature and saved it. The confirmed button should be disabled for that order no 1 for next time.

**Flow is here**
Order no's= order no1, order no2, order no3 so on
**After clicking order no1**
next layout having the button name signature.after clicking on the signature button. it will send to next page with having 3 button's. button's are confirmed, picked and delivered. 
**Clicking on confirmed button**
a screen will pop up and signature is done that layout and send that signature on server.
**THING I WANT**
The Thing i want is once signature is saved and send to server the confirmed button should be disabled same functionality for other button's like picked button and delivered button. these button should be disabled for order no1.

I am attaching my code of signature page on which signature functionality is working.

**Code of Signature page of have 3 buttons "confirmed,picked,delivered**

```
package com.example.demo_kaizen;



import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class popp_upp extends Activity {

    Button confirm, Delivered,pciked,done_image,clear_image;

    final String odddr_id=Staticcontent._order_id;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.pop_up);
        StrictMode.enableDefaults();
        done_image=(Button) findViewById(R.id.DoneButton);
        clear_image=(Button) findViewById(R.id.ClearButton);


        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),i_d,2000 ).show();


        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Staticcontent.driver_id, 2000).show();

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 8) {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                    .permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        }









        // Delivered=(Button) findViewById(R.id.tvDelivered);
        confirm = (Button) findViewById(R.id.tvConfirmed);



        confirm.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Staticcontent._confirm_sign = "confirmed";
                Intent intent = new Intent(popp_upp.this, Esignature.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                confirm.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });
    }



/*=====================================================
code for delivry sign*/



    public void delvi(View v) {
        Staticcontent._confirm_sign = "delivered";
        Intent intent = new Intent(popp_upp.this, Esignature.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }



/*=====================================================
code for picked sign*/

    public void picked(View v) {
        Staticcontent._confirm_sign = "picked";
        Intent intent = new Intent(popp_upp.this, Esignature.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //  super.onBackPressed();

    Intent intent=new Intent(popp_upp.this,Itemm_dashboard.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

**Code of Signature saving and sending to server**

```
package com.example.demo_kaizen;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.HttpMultipartMode;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntity;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.FileBody;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.StringBody;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.params.BasicHttpParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpConnectionParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.gesture.GestureOverlayView;
import android.gesture.GestureOverlayView.OnGestureListener;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Esignature extends Activity {

    String SERVER_URL = "http://showcase.pcubelive.com/kaizen/app_api/signature_api.php";
    String attachmentName = "image";
    String attachmentFileName = "image.jpg";
    String crlf = "\r\n";
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary = "*****";

    GestureOverlayView gestureView;
    String path;
    File file;
    Bitmap bitmap;
    public boolean gestureTouch = false;

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.esign_main);
        getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

        Button donebutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.DoneButton);
        donebutton.setText("Done");
        Button clearButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ClearButton);
        clearButton.setText("Clear");

        path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/signature.JPEG";
        file = new File(path);
        file.delete();
        gestureView = (GestureOverlayView) findViewById(R.id.signaturePad);
        gestureView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

        gestureView.setAlwaysDrawnWithCacheEnabled(true);
        gestureView.setHapticFeedbackEnabled(false);
        gestureView.cancelLongPress();
        gestureView.cancelClearAnimation();
        gestureView.addOnGestureListener(new OnGestureListener() {

            @Override
            public void onGesture(GestureOverlayView arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onGestureCancelled(GestureOverlayView arg0,
                    MotionEvent arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onGestureEnded(GestureOverlayView arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onGestureStarted(GestureOverlayView arg0,
                    MotionEvent arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (arg1.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
                    gestureTouch = false;
                } else {
                    gestureTouch = true;
                }
            }
        });

        donebutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                new PostSignature(Esignature.this).execute();
            }
        });

        clearButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                gestureView.invalidate();
                gestureView.clear(true);
                gestureView.clearAnimation();
                gestureView.cancelClearAnimation();
            }
        });
    }

    private class PostSignature extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>
    {
        ProgressDialog pDialog = null;

        public PostSignature(Context context)
        {
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.setMessage("Uploading Signature...");
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(gestureView.getDrawingCache());
                File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(), "sign.jpg");
                FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(f);
                bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 70, fout);
                fout.close();
                MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
                entity.addPart("image", new FileBody(f));

                SharedPreferences mshare = PreferenceManager
                        .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());

                entity.addPart("order_id", new StringBody(Staticcontent._order_id));
                entity.addPart("signature_id", new StringBody(Staticcontent._confirm_sign));
                entity.addPart("txt_user_email", new StringBody(mshare.getString("vkey", "vikram")));

                HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams(); 
                HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, 20000);
                HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, 20000);
                DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);

                HttpPost request = new HttpPost(SERVER_URL);
                request.setEntity(entity);

                HttpResponse response = null;
                response = client.execute(request);
                BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
                StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
                String line = "";
                while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                    result.append(line);
                }
                String res = result.toString();
                if(res.toLowerCase().contains("done")
                        || res.toLowerCase().contains("ok")
                        || res.toLowerCase().contains("success"))
                    return true;
            }catch(Throwable ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result)
        {
            if(pDialog != null && pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();
            //
            if(result)
                Toast.makeText(Esignature.this, "Signature Submitted Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            else
                Toast.makeText(Esignature.this, "Failed to Submit Signature", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            if(result)
            {
                if (gestureTouch == false) {
                    setResult(0);
                    finish();
                } else {
                    setResult(1);
                    finish();
                }
            }
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

When the signature has been sent to the server and the server accepted it (*onPostExecute* called with true), locally save for that order that a signature has been provided. As in your provided code no information is given, how an Order is modeled, I can only guess that you maybe need to add an additional boolean property like *signatureProvided*.

When opening the order detail activity, check whether for that Order a signature has been provided, if that's the case disable the button by calling *button.setEnabled(false)*.